# Monitoring console for Marklogic Access

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I need to know what all roles and privileges need to assign a user for access the Monitoring console and Monitoring History Dashboard.

Thanks in Advance

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

The built in "manage-admin" role is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but i want not to give admin access to user. Onlu just access to monitoring console and can only see and monitor server, database , space , network , i/o etc .

Comment: In that case manage-user role is what you need as per the other answer

Answer (score 1):

While manage-admin should work, I think you only need manage-user. See the following:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/monitoring/intro#id_64051